# How kubernetes handles unhealthy coredns pod?

Tags: kubernetes, coredns, kubernetes-health-check

The below snippet is taken from default Corefile of coredns.

```
data:  
  Corefile: |    
  .:53 {
        errors
        health {
            lameduck 5s
        }
        ready
```

In this snippet, health plugin is used to report health status to http://localhost:8080/health. If 200 OK is reported means healthy coredns pod. But I have few queries,
If anything other than 200 OK is reported as health status of coredns pod, will kubernetes destroy and recreate the coredns pod ?  Or how it will be handled by kubernetes?

If coredns pod is unhealthy, how is it handled to make it healthy? will kubernetes automatically take care of ensuring a healthy coredns pod ? What is the advised lameduck duration? Based on what parameters, we can come to a appropriate lameduck duration.

It would be really helpful if anyone can comment on this. Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1):

I have coredns deployed on a cluster in the kube-system namespace:

*kubectl describe deploy coredns -n kube-system*

Output:
Liveness:     http-get http://:8080/health delay=60s timeout=5s period=10s #success=1 #failure=5
Readiness:    http-get http://:8181/ready delay=0s timeout=1s period=10s #success=1 #failure=3

The Liveness/Readiness probes that are used for this must be configured